# Generate Double Tap Event Android

Tags: android, events, android-event

How do i generate a double tap event on Android.

This is the implementation that i have done.

```
$event="/dev/event/event1"
$x=$1
$y=$2
sendevent $event 3 57 2421
sendevent $event 3 58 232
sendevent $event 3 53 $x
sendevent $event 3 54 $y
sendevent $event 0 0 0
sendevent $event 3 57 4294967295
sendevent $event 0 0 0
sendevent $event 3 57 2421
sendevent $event 3 58 232
sendevent $event 3 53 $x
sendevent $event 3 54 $y
sendevent $event 0 0 0
sendevent $event 3 57 4294967295
sendevent $event 0 0 0
```

With this implementation the double tap is slow that it appears as two separate single taps to the android system.

P.S: I tried these on Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to implement your custom double tab event? Maybe you can use [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html), this listener has method [onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDoubleTap%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) listens to the double tap gesture. All i want to do is to generate one. Not catch the gesture. 

There is a way to simulate a tap event `adb shell input tap <x> <y>` but i want to figure out how to simulate doubletap.